# for loop adding the last extracted data set to every position in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

So I am 100% positive I am doing something stupid here:

```
function storeData(){

    for (var i in json.result){ 

        var pair = json.result[i]
        marketName = pair.MarketName
        price = pair.Last

        extractedData[i,0] = marketName
        extractedData[i,1] = price
        totalExtractedData[i] = extractedData
    }
    console.log(totalExtractedData)
}
```

The problem is that rather than creating an array with each successive market name and last price in each row (~260 rows), its returning an array ~260 in size, but with the very last extracted data set in every single row:

```
[ [ 'USDT-ZEC', 235.00000001 ],
  [ 'USDT-ZEC', 235.00000001 ],
  [ 'USDT-ZEC', 235.00000001 ],
  [ 'USDT-ZEC', 235.00000001 ],
  [ 'USDT-ZEC', 235.00000001 ]..]
```

This is the json file in question:

https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries

I have tested every permutation I can think of but I'm positive it is something head slappingly simple.

Any insight would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems you're not creating a new `extractedData` object on each iteration but updating the existing one. Create a new `extractedData` object as the first line in the loop

Comment: And do you really need it to be an array or arrays or an array of objects?

Comment: You can't access a 2-dimensional array with `extractedData[i,0]` syntax. It's `extractedData[i][0]`

Comment: What I am trying to do is create an array with the market name in the first "column" and then each successive column is a list of prices extracted at set intervals. I will then pass this array to a different function which will perform some calculations on the retrieved data. I have the initialization of the array working, but am now struggling to add new data without wiping old data :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the totalExtractedData var declared outside the loop

```
function storeData(){
    var totalExtractedData;
    for (var i in json.result){ 

        var pair = json.result[i]
        marketName = pair.MarketName
        price = pair.Last

        extractedData[i,0] = marketName
        extractedData[i,1] = price
        totalExtractedData[i] = extractedData
    }
    console.log(totalExtractedData)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work as "totalExtractedData[i] = extractedData" returns "Cannot set  property '0' of  undefined".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Perhaps this will do:

```
extractedData = [];
for (var i in json.result){
    console.log(i);
    var pair = json.result[i]
    marketName = pair.MarketName
    price = pair.Last
    extractedData.push([marketName,price]);
}
console.log(extractedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

I think your problems are the way you are declaring variables and how you are pushing the values in your array:

If you deaclare the variable `extractedData` without `var` keyword it will be global variable and will be always updated with the last iterated values, so when you push this variable in the array it will point for the same array variable.

**Solution:**

If you want to push in two dimension array you need to use `array[i][0]` instead of `arrat[i,0]`.

You need to replace :

```
extractedData[i,0] = marketName
extractedData[i,1] = price
totalExtractedData[i] = extractedData
```

With the following:

```
totalExtractedData[i] = [];
totalExtractedData[i][0] = marketName;
totalExtractedData[i][1] = price;
```

**Demo:**

This is how should be your function:

```js
var json = {
  "success": true,
  "message": "",
  "result": [{
    "MarketName": "BITCNY-BTC",
    "High": 31053.62881383,
    "Low": 27015.85000000,
    "Volume": 44.06800758,
    "Last": 29569.95000000,
    "BaseVolume": 1271058.32726181,
    "TimeStamp": "2017-08-25T10:24:04.07",
    "Bid": 28702.45000000,
    "Ask": 31000.00000000,
    "OpenBuyOrders": 36,
    "OpenSellOrders": 49,
    "PrevDay": 27355.00000000,
    "Created": "2015-12-11T06:31:40.653"
  }, {
    "MarketName": "BTC-1ST",
    "High": 0.00016199,
    "Low": 0.00015267,
    "Volume": 552059.58404200,
    "Last": 0.00016171,
    "BaseVolume": 86.52132446,
    "TimeStamp": "2017-08-25T10:24:30.113",
    "Bid": 0.00016171,
    "Ask": 0.00016199,
    "OpenBuyOrders": 187,
    "OpenSellOrders": 3530,
    "PrevDay": 0.00015480,
    "Created": "2017-06-06T01:22:35.727"
  }, {
    "MarketName": "BTC-2GIVE",
    "High": 0.00000121,
    "Low": 0.00000113,
    "Volume": 4931418.39409932,
    "Last": 0.00000118,
    "BaseVolume": 5.74430002,
    "TimeStamp": "2017-08-25T10:22:58.64",
    "Bid": 0.00000118,
    "Ask": 0.00000119,
    "OpenBuyOrders": 263,
    "OpenSellOrders": 1921,
    "PrevDay": 0.00000113,
    "Created": "2016-05-16T06:44:15.287"
  }]
};

function storeData() {
  var totalExtractedData = [];
  for (var i in json.result) {
    var pair = json.result[i];
    var marketName = pair.MarketName;
    var price = pair.Last;
    totalExtractedData[i] = [];
    totalExtractedData[i][0] = marketName;
    totalExtractedData[i][1] = price;
  }
  console.log(totalExtractedData);
}

storeData();
```

**Note:**

Bear thes points in mind when you write JavaScript code:

- Declare your variables with `var` so they will be local to the function, otherwise you will have global varibales.
- Missing semicolons `;` in each statement is a bad practice, you
  better place a `;` at the end of each line.

Comment: Thank you. I was aware that the way I was addressing my arrays was likely incorrect, but I was just struggling to get anything working so went with what sort of appeared to be the right direction. I have an additional question but no room to ask it. Hopefully there is no problem posting again.

Comment: Yes there will be no problem to ask another question :) But you can just ask it here in comments and we will tell you if it's worth it to post it as another one.

Answer (score 0):

You're simply overwriting the same `exctractedData` array each time through the loop, and `totalExtractedData` has multiple references to this same array. You need to create a new `extractedData` array each time through the loop.

```
function storeData(){
    var totalExtractedData = [];
    var extractedData;
    for (var i in json.result){ 
        var pair = json.result[i];
        extractedData = [];
        extractedData[0] = pair.MarketName;
        extractedData[1] = pair.Last;
        totalExtractedData.push(extractedData);
    }
    console.log(totalExtractedData)
}
```

Also, there's no reason to use `i` in the indexes of `extractedData`. `exctractedData[i, 0]` is the same as `extractedData[0]`, since the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) simply returns its second operand.

Comment: Thanks. It's pretty obvious to me now! Question - is there a way to address the inner array and add a new entry to it? Basically I want to run this function repeatedly, and after the first run when the market name and initial price are added, I want to then add each successive price. Everything I've done just overwrites what is already there. I've tried dozens of different methods but the presence of extractedData = [] inside the loop keeps wiping the existing array. So my array is growing in size, but all the previous entries are listed as "empty". I need to keep old data as new data is added

Comment: You can use `extractedData = totalExtractedData[i]` to get the array that was already saved previously, then you can modify it.

Comment: If I replace  extractedData = []; with  extractedData = totalExtractedData[i], I simply get "TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined" on the line "extractedData[0] = pair.MarketName;". This is a problem I see repeatedly when I try a new solution which makes me believe I do not understand what is actually happening. Obviously lol. My initial plan was to simply recall the previous state of the array but it fails in the same way every time.

Comment: You can only use that when `totalExtractedData` is already filled in. When you're filling it in the first time, you have to create new arrays.

Comment: You could use `extractedData = totalExtractedData[i] || [];`. This will get the existing entry if it exists, otherwise default to a new, empty array. This is a basic Javascript idiom.

Comment: Holy sh*t I think I got it working! I included an if/else statement to check if it was the first run through and assigned items to the array accordingly. I have plans on taking it much further, but I might let this sink in for a day or 2 first. Thank you so much for you help!